# Include Susy with Nanoc

Tags: compilation, sass, nanoc

I'm trying to include [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) in my Nanoc project.
I followed the GitHub of ddfreyne. I installed Compass first and Susy next. Then, in my `Gemfile` I added the line: `gem "susy"`.
In my stylesheet, I added `@import "susy"` Unfortunately, I have an error during the compilation which is `Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: suzy.` I don't understand this error...
I'm using SASS to make my stylesheets.
I hope you'll be able to help me! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was quite simple. I had to replace `@import "suzy` by `@import "susy"` in my stylesheet.